# How to Count Status That Have a Same Value in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I want the output to show the number of transaction and status. If the same number has made successful transactions (which is status=0), it would count as 1 success even if the same number has made a few transaction.

```
SELECT CAST(t.DATE AS DATE) AS DATE
    ,(t.TRANSACTION + r.Request) AS allTransaction
    ,(t.Success + r.RequestSuccess) AS allSuccess
    ,t.TRANSACTION
    ,t.Success
    ,r.Request
    ,r.RequestSuccess
FROM (
    SELECT DATE
        ,count(DISTINCT no_a) AS TRANSACTION
        ,count(t.STATUS) AS Success
    FROM transfer_tx_201503 AS t
    WHERE STATUS = 0
        AND cast(DATE AS TIME) BETWEEN "00:00:00"
            AND "15:00:00"
    GROUP BY CAST(DATE AS DATE)
    ) AS t
JOIN (
    SELECT DATE
        ,count(DISTINCT no_a) AS Request
        ,count(r.STATUS) AS RequestSuccess
    FROM request_tx_201503 AS r
    WHERE STATUS = 0
    GROUP BY CAST(DATE AS DATE)
    ) AS r ON CAST(t.DATE AS DATE) = CAST(r.DATE AS DATE)
GROUP BY DATE DESC;
```

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Also, please make a sqlfiddle with the sample data.

Comment: Would love to help but I don't know what you need. Show an example of the desired result, what you have tried, and the incorrect result you got.